# OpenSSL Vulnerability/Update

Tags: openssl, vulnerability

I am receiving a critical vulnerability on Ubuntu 20.04 for OpenSSL. The vulnerability is calling for an update from 1.1.1f to 1.1.1l. I have 1.1.1q installed. Is this a false-positive?

Comment: Without a specific CVE to check, the question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the specific CVE against the [Ubuntu CVE Tracker](https://ubuntu.com/security/cves) to see if any action is needed.

Most folks receive updated packages (patched to mitigate High/Critical CVEs) completely automatically via the Ubuntu `<release>-security` apt repository or via their snap packages.